# controller.ts(8,8): error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request' while extending express.Request

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am getting below error. Please help me.

```
controller.ts(8,8): error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request'.
```

## controller.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
class Users{
 public showUser(
    req: express.Request,
    res: express.Response,
    next: express.NextFunction
  ) {
     return req.user;

 }
}
const users = new Users();
export = {
 showUser: users.showUser
}
```

## express.custommerge.d.ts

```
// Extend the Express interface with declaration merging
import { User } from './api';
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    user: User; 
  }
}
```

## api.ts

```
export class User {
 'userId': string
}
```

## Note:

This is error does not come if i don't include `import { User } from './api';` in express.custommerge.d.ts with adding `any` instead of `User`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if i make below changes in

## express.custommerge.d.ts

```
import { User } from './api';
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    user: User; 
  }
}
```